# How to debug @font-face problems?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have the following CSS code:

```
// theMixPlainSemiBold
@font-face {
    font-family: 'theMixPlainSemiBold';
    src: url('/css/fonts/... .eot');
    src: url('/css/fonts/... .eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/css/fonts/... .svg#TheMixPlainSemiBoldSemiBold') format('svg'),
         url('/css/fonts/... .woff') format('woff'),
         url('/css/fonts/... .ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I expect that this creates a new font family called `theMixPlainSemiBold`.

After importing this font I do:

```
.box {
    ...
    font-family: 'theMixPlainSemiBold', sans-serif;
    ...
}
```

I have the `box` class that have `theMixPlainSemiBold` font family.

When I open the page I see `sans-serif` font in the `.box`.

What can be the problem? Same is happening for the other local web fonts while it works good with Google Fonts.

How can I debug the font problems? I don't see any errors/warnings in developer tools. It looks for me like the font is not loaded from local files...

Comment: do you have a live demo link we can have a look?

Comment: @Godinall No, sorry...

Comment: Can you check which of the fonts are downloading in Firefox/chrome?

Comment: @SurjithSM In the `Developer Tools (Chrome) > Network > Fonts` I don't see this font... It seems that it is not loaded in the page.

Comment: Are you sure these fonts are in the correct path?

Comment: @SurjithSM Yes, I am sure. The problem was with the `//` comments. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20900572/1420197).

Comment: The answer my friend is blowing in the wind... (@IonicăBizău :)) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is not a real answer to the question, I found the problem myself. Double-slashes  (`//`) are not valid CSS comments! See this screenshot from Developer Tools:

> [image]

So, my code becomes:

```
/* theMixPlainSemiBold */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'theMixPlainSemiBold';
    src: url('/css/fonts/... .eot');
    src: url('/css/fonts/... .eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/css/fonts/... .svg#TheMixPlainSemiBoldSemiBold') format('svg'),
         url('/css/fonts/... .woff') format('woff'),
         url('/css/fonts/... .ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The fonts are correctly loaded now.

Comment: Double-slashes are no valid CSS comments, right, but does it make any difference? I saw them several times and they work anyway.

Comment: @kleinfreund Yes, this make the difference.

Comment: Sure, I see it. But how is this possible? Shouldn't the line with the invalid comment be ignored alltogether?

Comment: @kleinfreund As per my knowledge, when there is an invalid line in CSS, The code below the line won't work.

Comment: I asked [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20900693/1420197) for that.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question, no? Your question was *How can I debug the font problems*. But the answer is *I put a double slash into my font*. Though this tells me how to fix this particular problem, it doesn't help with the general problem of how to debug issues, generally, like the question title suggests. Maybe change the title?

Comment: @Liam True... In fact, I don't think there is a real solution to the problem... Dev tools could be useful anyway.

Comment: While this answer may not _technically_ answer the problem, it solved my issue perfectly – it was certainly useful _while_ I was trying to debug my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @spikeheap Nice! Glad to hear that it still helps people after years. :) You're welcome!

Answer (score 10):

First, using an unambiguous custom `font-family` name may help debugging since it will prevent your local fonts to be triggered and used.

Then, while this is not restricted to `@font-face` issues, Firefox developper tools' console can surely help debugging CSS issues.

In your case, it would have detected the bad comments:

```
Selector expected.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  yourfile.css:23
```

In my case, due to bad editing after a copypasta I had a trailing comma instead of a semicolon, which prevented Firefox to download the font:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: SuperFont;
    src: url('../fonts/Superfont.ttf'),
}
```

The console came up with:

```
Error in parsing value for ‘src’.  Skipped to next declaration.  myfile:18
```

Or the console may complain about:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "myfont" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): status=2147746065 source: url/to/font.otf
```

(This would typically follow a 404 on the font URL, damned typos…)

Comment: Thank you for the tip about using the console! Huge help.

Answer (score 2):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: anyname;
    src: url('folder/folder2/folder3/theMixPlainSemiBold.ttf');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}
```

then use it like this:

```
#sample{
    font-family:anyname;
}
```

you can use any name in it. `/` is important in the url because it shows that it is inside a folder.

Comment: This was my problem.. every wrote how to make a `@font-face` but nobody wrote that you had to manually apply it to elements! I asumed it would just apply to the whole page by default. Doh. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're prototyping and watching your freshly generated HTML as static, local files, the fonts might not load. ( Because of some cross-domain policies by the browser?)

So, would need to request your html via a (local) server.

Answer (score -1):

please check your link to source

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'theMixPlainSemiBold';
  src: url('../css/fonts/.eot');
  src: url('../css/fonts/.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../css/fonts/.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../css/fonts/.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../css/fonts/.svg#open_sanslight') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

maybe you forgot about `../` because if fonts from google working normal so your link (source) your font must be wrong

Comment: your code is correct, so problem is with source, you must check you link to this font. Open you browser, show source your website and check links to your font. I use ../ because maybe you links is not correct. Please check links to fonts.

Comment: I found [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20900572/1420197). My problem is finally solved. Thanks.

Comment: I had this same exact problem and removing the single line comment style was the fix.  However, just wanted to add that firebug was more helpful in solving this over chrome debugger, as it shows you the fonts as they are being rendered when you hover over the font family name; chrome does not.  This was helpful since my custom font was somewhat similar to the default sans-serif being pulled in.