# How are the invalid CSS lines interpreted?

Tags: css

I spent about 30 minutes to [debug a font loading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20900218/1420197) problem in a page and I finally found that I was using wrong comment:

```
// this is a comment
@font-face {
   /* is this ignored? */
   ...
}

.box {
  border: ... /* this was not ignored */
}
```

After changing `//` in `/* ... */` the fonts are correctly loaded.

So, my question is: *How are the invalid CSS lines interpreted?* Are they just ignored or the other CSS properties are affected?

The example above is just an example. The question is about general invalid lines.

A good official reference is welcome.

Comment: In fact, there aren't many possibilities. They cannot be honoured since, well, they aren't valid. And the whole CSS file is definitively not discarded with a parse error (otherwise, CSS hacks would be pointless and CSS validators wouldn't be necessary). You just had a lucky typo that interacted badly with your browser's CSS parser.

Comment: The reason why this works is not because it's a comment, but because it's nothing CSS knows and therefor treats it as a comment. Right?

Comment: CSS is just a style sheet which is added to DOM objects in the page once they are loaded and matched. Hence , yes. It is ignored if the properties doesn't match.

Comment: Check this [__demo__](http://jsfiddle.net/9uWU2/1/). Just like you said in the comment of your other question.

Comment: `// ...` isn't a comment in CSS. `url(//mysite.com/mybg.png)` would then be invalid!

Comment: @techfoobar That's a good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing about `/` is that it doesn't appear anywhere in the CSS2.1 grammar outside of a comment delimiter or a string, so if you're looking at the [grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#tokenization), it's hard to tell how it'd affect stylesheet parsing exactly.

It could count as a malformed selector, because the basic building block of CSS consists of a selector and a declaration block (collectively a rule set), but since `/` does not appear in the Selectors grammar except in string values, which selectors are not, I would hesitate to consider it as a selector.

I would say that in this specific case, it's just a generic [statement that's malformed](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors):

> - **Malformed statements.** User agents must handle unexpected tokens encountered while parsing a statement by reading until the end of the statement, while observing the rules for matching pairs of (), [], {}, "", and '', and correctly handling escapes. For example, a malformed statement may contain an unexpected closing brace or at-keyword. E.g., the following lines are all ignored:
>
>   ```
>   p @here {color: red}     /* ruleset with unexpected at-keyword "@here" */
>   @foo @bar;               /* at-rule with unexpected at-keyword "@bar" */
>   }} {{ - }}               /* ruleset with unexpected right brace */
>   ) ( {} ) p {color: red } /* ruleset with unexpected right parenthesis */
>   ```

A statement is defined as either a rule set, or an at-rule, which usually consist of some token, followed by a pair of curly braces (`{}`) or anything up to the next semicolon (`;`). Note again that none of the examples here have `/`, but since it is an unexpected character in a generic statement, it's expected that it'd cause your entire `@font-face` "rule" to be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#comments) :

> Comments begin with the characters "/*" and end with the characters
>   "*/". They may occur anywhere outside other tokens, and their contents
>   have no influence on the rendering. Comments may not be nested.

Further, Section 4.2 Rules for handling parsing errors

> In some cases, user agents must ignore part of an illegal style sheet.
>   This specification defines ignore to mean that the user agent parses
>   the illegal part (in order to find its beginning and end), but
>   otherwise acts as if it had not been there.

So not only `//`, even if you have an invalid selector, it will skip the next block entirely and will move to second one.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kBWP9/) *Stray `a` selector, and the second property block just fails as there are no `{}` after*

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/kBWP9/1/) *a selector with braces `{}`*

So in general, it's not the invalid comment there, but it's an invalid statement which causes an issue to parse your stylesheet correctly..

Answer (score 3):

From the [Official Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#error-handling)

This rule is what you are seeing:

- At the "top level" of a stylesheet, an at-keyword-token starts an
  at-rule. Anything else starts a qualified rule, and is included in
  the rule’s prelude. This may produce an invalid selector, but that’s
  not the concern of the CSS parser — at worst, it means the selector
  will match nothing.

That is to say, your "//" is treated as introducing a qualified rule, so the interpreter is trying to match nodes using the selector "// this is a comment @font-face", which it will obviously fail to do, because that makes no sense.

This is another rule that you are very likely to experience:

- When interpreting a list of declarations, unknown syntax at any point
  causes the parser to throw away whatever declaration it’s currently
  building, and seek forward until it finds a semicolon (or the end of
  the block). It then starts fresh, trying to parse a declaration again.

Comment: "*This section is not normative.*" But I suppose it's good enough, at least it clarifies something that is not even mentioned in [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors).

Comment: @BoltClock Good point.  Also the whole document is at Last Call, rather than Recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

load the page on browser and then 
**right click->inspect element**.You get a window bottom of browser, right side of that window in style section all style attributes for corresponding control are specified.Invalid style attributes are cross lined.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.. I don't see my `//` commnet cross lined and it is an invalid line.

Comment: Look this.......,  
color: red;
padding: www;  Second one is invalid , So it displays as strikethrough